# how to seperate each variable in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

so, I have an ajax call that displays my JSON like this:

```
{"main_object":{"id":"new","formData":"language=nl_NL&getExerciseTitle=test&question_takeAudio_exerciseWord%5B0%5D=test&Syllablescounter%5B0%5D=test&Syllablescounter%5B1%5D=test"}}
```

but I would like to have it like this:

```
{"main_object":{"language":"nl_NL","getExerciseTitle":"asd","question_takeAudio_exerciseWord":["asd"],"Syllablescounter":["ASDasd",""]}}
```

The only thing I want to add is the "id":"new".

This is my ajax call (my JSON starts looking like the first one with my ajax call)

```
 function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
  $("#my_form").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
              url: 'saveJson.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {id: getUrlParameter('id'), formData: $('#my_form').serialize()},
              dataType: 'json',
          }).done(function (response) {
              window.location = 'index.php';
          });
 });
}
```

edit: Ouni wanted me to show what is going on in the php script so here it is:

```
<?php
include_once('database_json.php');
$data = $_POST;
//Setup an empty array.
 $errors = array();
if (isset($data)) {
$newExerciseData['main_object'] = $data;
$exerciseArray = $data['main_object'];
$databaseFile = 'json_files/database.json';
$textContent = file_get_contents($databaseFile);
$database = json_decode($textContent, true);
if ($data['id'] === 'new') {
    if (count($database['data']) == 0) {
        $ID = 0;
    } // ending database['data'] count 0.
    else {
        $maxID = max($database['data']);
        $ID = ++$maxID["id"];
    } // ending the max ID else statement.
    $newJsonFile = 'jsonData_' . $ID . '.json';
    $newJsonFilePath = 'json_files/' . $newJsonFile;
    //Create new database exercise_txt
    $newArrayData = array(
        'id' => $ID,
        'exercisetitle' => $data['formData']['getExerciseTitle'],
        'language' => $data['formData']['language'],
        'file' => $newJsonFile
    );
    $database['data'][] = $newArrayData;
} // } op regel 34 lijkt verdwaald...?
else {
    $index = array_search((int) $_POST['id'], array_column($database['data'], 'id'));
    $correctJsonFile = 'json_files/jsonData_' . $_POST['id'] . '.json';
    $newJsonFile = 'jsonData_' . $_POST['id'] . '.json';
    $newJsonFilePath = 'json_files/' . $newJsonFile;
    //Create new database exercise_txt
    $newArrayData2 = array(
        'id' => (int) $data['id'],
        'exercisetitle' => $data['formData']['getExerciseTitle'],
        'language' => $data['formData']['language'],
        'file' => $newJsonFile
    );
    $database['data'][$index] = $newArrayData2;
} // closing off the else statement
$newExerciseData['main_object'] = $database['data'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
file_put_contents($databaseFile, json_encode($database, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
file_put_contents($newJsonFilePath, json_encode($newExerciseData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
echo json_encode($newExerciseData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
} //closing off the if isset.
```

how could this be achieved? I know it isn't my saveJson.php that's the problem. I know it's my ajax call since it starts showing like the first JSON piece of code when I add the id: getUrlParameter('id')

Comment: If you want the data in that form, why are you generating it using `$('#my_form').serialize()` in the first place?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:javascript] but your are POSTing the data to a URL with `.php` on the end, so isn't the code trying to prase the JSON and convert the data into the format you want going to be PHP?

Comment: If you're going to reload the page when the POST is complete, why use ajax at all? Why not just do an ordinary form post?

Comment: That was something I had before I added the id: getUrlParameter('id') piece of code, but since that piece is added it displays like the first one, and i'm not entirely sure if that's causing the problem or not, i'm quite a newb in javascript/json

Comment: "I have an ajax call that displays my JSON" — The JavaScript's `done` function just sets `location` to a new URL. It doesn't display any JSON.

Comment: Welp, maybe I should not have said that my ajax call displays the JSON. What I meant is: When I send the info, my JSON ends up looking like the first piece of code. That is what I meant with "I have an ajax call that displays my JSON" :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to focus on your question itself without regard for the perfectly valid comments made about your overall approach, it looks like you have data in a querystring format and you want to parse it into a JSON format. The quesrystring format is the data that looks like this:

```
language=nl_NL&getExerciseTitle=test
```

And you ultimately wants this:

```
{
  language: "nl_NL",
  getExerciseTitle: "test"
}
```

and so on.

One way to accomplish this is to use an existing library that does precisely that for you. For example, the [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) package.

For example, given a string:

```
 const result = "language=nl_NL&getExerciseTitle=test";
 const parsed = queryString.parse(result);
```

will produce the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to parse your query string in vanilla JavaScript, without installing a third-party package:

```
const start = {"main_object":{"id":"new","formData":"language=nl_NL&getExerciseTitle=test&question_takeAudio_exerciseWord%5B0%5D=test&Syllablescounter%5B0%5D=test&Syllablescounter%5B1%5D=test"}}
const temp = Object.assign({}, start);
temp.formData = decodeURIComponent(start.main_object.formData)
  .split("&")
  .reduce((result, data) => {
    const components = data.split("=");
    let prop_name = components[0];
    const prop_value = components[1];
    const array_char_index = prop_name.indexOf('[');

    if (array_char_index > 0) {
      prop_name = prop_name.substring(0, array_char_index);
      if (result[prop_name] === undefined) { result[prop_name] = []; }
      result[prop_name].push(prop_value);
    }
    else {
      result[prop_name] = prop_value;
    }
    return result;
  }, {})
;
console.log(temp.formData);
```

I recommend using vanilla JS whenever possible, so that you learn the concepts, and so you can adapt it to your own needs, when you find yourself wanting more.

Comment: Oke, but the const start needs data assigned to it I guess? but how will this be done whenever you insert data? how will it take the data and transform it into the JSON I am looking for? thanks for the code/help btw

Comment: It is unclear what data you are feeding into the ajax function, what the PHP code is doing to parse it, and what you expect to get back as a result, so any further details I could give you would only be a guess.  Maybe you can discover these details for yourself, and edit the question with more info?  Good luck!